# Unable to locate package postgresql "version"

Tags: postgresql, linux-mint

I'm having this problem while installing postgres version 11.5 on Linux Mint 19.3

```
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-11.5

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-11.5
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'postgresql-11.5'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-11.5'
```

Comment: Why do you want an older version including bugs that have been fixed? Leave the patch-number out and it should work: sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-11

Comment: If you need the speicific minor version, you could to [build](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/installation.html) it from [sources](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/v11.5/).

Comment: @FrankHeikens Sometimes you need to have the same version as on the production servers...

Comment: See this post [Archived](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20160731194944.amiwidhsoqh4osac%40msg.df7cb.de). Though I don't see 11.5 in the archives. There is 11.4 then it jumps to 11.7.

Comment: @Abelisto: Do you really want something with bugs? Version 11.5 and 11.10 are the same version. Version 11.10 has been patched to the latest patch round, where 11.5 is 5 patch rounds behind.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Have you heard about the philosophy "If it works, don't touch it"? It have pros and cons ofcourse but try to explain it to managers.